# Libre Office Calc: Export to CSV with CRLF line endings

Tags: libreoffice, csv

I need to be able to save files created in LibreOffice Calc to CSV with the CRLF line endings.

I have tried many options but the files always come out missing the CR part.

I work with programs that will not import the CSV files without the windows line endings.

Comment: Convert to CSV as you normally would, then use the `unix2dos` command on the files.

Comment: There are no options related to line endings in the [filter options](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options), so it looks like the only way is to use an external tool.  Of course, a custom macro could be written to do this, for example using Python [open()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).  Or perhaps a custom [XSLT export filter](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Creating_XML_Filters) could do it.

Comment: It is quite a while later; but this is still an issue. I usually just save the CSV file now and open and resave using gedit which allows choosing the line endings.

Answer (score 2):

Line termination is not part of the CSV specification. It depends on the operating system. If you work on linux you get LF; if you use windows, CRLF. 
When exporting any kind of text files from linux to windows a conversion tool is required: unix2dos.

Comment: I know; and it is a PITA. Gedit allows me to choose line endings....why not Libre Office. \

Answer (score 1):

I was automating a bunch of other stuff so I thought I would automate this also.

Using the Unix2dos command mentioned above; I now press F12 (open terminal in current folder) and type csv.

This is aliased to 'unix2dos *.csv' which is much faster then re-opening the files every time. I have tested that unix2dos doesn't do anything weird to the file if it is run more then once on the same file.

Notes:
Getting F12 to open a terminal in the current folder.
go to ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts add a scripts called whatever (Terminal)
in the script place

```
# !/bin/sh
gnome-terminal
```

Then go to ~/.config/nautilus/script-accels and add the shortcut you want; I set F12.

```
F12 <script name> (Terminal)
```